# Delete files the same size in CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to delete files the same size  and retain the distinct file, but My code is not working properly. How can i fix it.

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (.\*) do (
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a count=0
set /a fsize=%%~zi
for /r %%j in (.\*) do (
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if %%~zj EQU !fsize!
set /a count=count+1
if !count! GTR 1
del %%j ))
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "it's not working properly." What is it supposed to be doing, and what is it _actually_ doing? I'm not going to run your code, but just by glancing at it, I can tell you that `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` should absolutely _NOT_ be inside of `for` loops - you only need one and it should go on the second line of the script. Also, indent your code.

Comment: Thanks SomethingDark. I move "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" outside of for loops. But it still not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few issues. Commands preceding if should be on the same line. You cannot do two `delayedexpansion`s inside of `for` loops without ending them with `endlocal` as the expansion will run too deep.

So you only need one `delayedexpansion` outside the loop. The main problem here is that you will **always** have a count of 2 or more in the second loop as the second `for` starts the recursive search again and each file will match itself, including the `batch-file`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%i in (*) do (
    if not "%%~i" == "%~f0" (
       set "fsize=%%~zi"
       for /r %%j in (*) do (
         if !fsize! equ %%~zj if not "%%~j" == "%%~i" if exist "%%~i" del "%%~i"
  )
 )
)
```

You must note however, this will recurse into the subfolders becuase of `for /R` So if a file exists in the root dir of 6KB as an example and a file in a subfolder also has a size of 6KB will it delete the root file and keep the file in the subfolder. It will delete all files but the last in the list with the same size.